# Differentiating/Integrating the argument of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-integration

I recently stumbled upon some weird notation:
$$\int_J \text{d}\arg f(z)$$
where $f$ is a holomorphic function on an open domain $Ω$, $J\subset Ω$ is a simple closed real analytic curve and $\arg f$ is just the argument of $f$.

Is this equal to 
$$\frac{1}{2πi}\int_J\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\text{d}z$$
(and why) or have I misunderstood something?

And if these two are **not** equal, then can we somehow exploit the argument principle to say something about the zeroes of $f$ inside $J$ using the **first** integral?

EDIT: The domain $Ω$ is not necessarily simply connected.

Comment: You are right in writing the question. But it will be better if you write $\int_Jd\log f(z)$.

Comment: What do you mean that I'm right?
I know the second integral is equal to $\int_J d\log f(z)$, but don't want that; I want the argument of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$J$ is a curve, that is, it can be expressible as $J(t) : [0,1] \to \Bbb C$. The definition of this integral is:

$$\int_J d\arg f(z) = \int_0^1 \frac {d\arg f(J(t))}{dt}\, dt$$

One might think that by the FTC, this would be $\arg f(J(1)) - \arg f(J(0)) = 0$, since $J(0) = J(1)$. But the intent here is to express $\arg f(J(t))$ as a continuous function. That is, if $\arg f(J(t))$ should rise up to $2\pi$ and the curve continue to move in the same direction, the value of the argument will continue to rise instead of dropping back to $0$. Thus $J$ can return to the same point, but the argument will pick up a multiple of $2\pi$.

So in fact, $$\int_J d\arg f(z) = 2\pi k$$ where $k$ is the winding number of $f\circ J$ about $0$.